# Real time filtering of heart rate data

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I'm trying to build a heart rate monitor, which I intend to code a mobile application around. Currently, I'm receiving the data in my application. Heres an example of the data:

[image]

However, I really would like to be able to remove the static element below the pulsating curve through some sort of high pass filter. Currently, I have the following code:

```
//HIGH PASS 

//Fetch the next measurement item
j = float.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Characteristic.Value)); 
counter++;

total += j;
if (counter % 5 == 0)
{
    avg = total / counter;
    total = 0;
    counter = 0;
}

if (j < h || h > avg && h >= 0)
{
    h = j;

}
else if (h <= 0) //Initially h is 0
{
    h = j;
}

float g = j-(h-5); //This is the output
```

The code does to some degree work. What it does, is that it monitors the data and sets h=j if a lower value is present (by doing so, I constantly have the lowest point on the curve, which I can then remove). 
Furthermore, for every 5 data points, a new average is put. Primarily to constantly check whether the filter is set too high. (i have roughly 6 data points every second)

The code is not really optimal. One of the major flaws is, if I remove my finger from the Heart rate sensor (j is being significantly lower), meaning that the curve will have almost no HR sine curve. 
I could potentially add `h=avg;` to the counter if-statement. But that would cause the curve to constantly flicker up and down.

What are your suggestion guys? how can I tweak this?

Comment: what was the question? do you need a realtime scaling?

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is known as "_real-time baseline wander removal_". If you search for this key phrase on the web you could find descriptions of several algorithms that had been proven to work well on this problem. Might be a better strategy than investing in tweaking your method.